# Recover encrypted Oracle database

Tags: oracle, wallet, password

A client fired their DBA. He used OWM to add a wallet to their Oracle database and secure a few necessary columns of tables that they need. I can see the walled using:

```
orapki wallet display -wallet /opt/oracle/home/owm/root
```

I do not know the password. The ex-employee will not divulge the password. With root access to the system, is it possible to remove the wallet or change the wallet's password?

NOTE: Not part of this problem, but for reference... Oracle Support told the client they are out of luck. I told them they are out of luck. They want a third (and fourth (and fifth)) opinion.

Comment: There are places on Earth where this could be solved by rubber hose cryptanalysis: http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2008/10/rubber_hose_cry.html

Comment: They're f*****. I guess the feature served its purpose, but in the wrong way :) The only way to solve this is socially, so I'm going to vote to close the question. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't remove the wallet or change the password, but if the wallet is set to auto-open (or it is open) you should be able to export the data out of that database and create a new one that does not have an associated wallet.